# How to create the domain administrator of a Google Apps domain purchased via the reseller API

Tags: google-reseller-api

We are trying to build an application using the Reseller API that our customers will use to purchase Google Apps for Business domains online.

I would like to understand the step-by-step process that a new customer would go through. 
Here is my understanding, based on the documentation I found:

1) Customer visits our site, fills in the form with name, address, alternate email address, domain name

2) our application calls POST https://www.googleapis.com/apps/reseller/v1/customers to create a new Customer object

3) This is where it gets unclear. The documentation (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/reseller/v1/how-tos/manage_customers ) says that my application should "use the Provisioning API to create a new administrator in the new customer's account" . However the Provisioning API documentation (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#creating_an_administrator_account ) only explains a step by step procedure for the customer to create its own admin account, where he needs to accept terms and conditions and then do a Google Checkout to purchase the seats. 
I expected to be able to create the administrator account programmatically, but I don't understand how it is supposed to work ? 
Can you please give more details on how a fully programmatic purchase scenario (i.e. entirely driven by a reseller's application) is supposed to work ? Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

After creating the new customer, you also have to create a subscription. This includes what plan they are on and how many licenses they have, details are at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/reseller/v1/how-tos/manage_subscriptions#create_subscription.

Once the domain becomes a customer of your reseller account, you can use the Provisioning API to create user accounts, including admin accounts. Instructions for creating an new user are at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#creating_a_user_account, and the tag 'admin' should be set to 'true'. See https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/reference#xml_tag_def for all of the tags and their allowed values.